# php exec() not working with SOME of the windows environment variables

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to run a couple commands from PHP with **exec()** and it seems to work only for some of the commands defined in my windows environment variables but not for all. 
In my command prompt I can run all of this commands succesfully from any path (C:\ or E:\whatever)

```
> pear -V     // ... "PEAR Version: 1.9.5" ...
> dot -V      // dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
> phpdoc -V   // phpDocumentor version 2.8.1
```

All of them return the correct version for each of the specified programs, that means that the environment variables are well configured. 
But in PHP I can only run some commands, the rest of them fails:

```
$out = array();
$ret = '';

exec('pear -V', $out, $ret);
echo var_dump($out); // $ret = 0, $out = array ..."PEAR Version: 1.9.5" ...

exec('phpdoc -V', $out, $ret);
echo var_dump($out); // $ret = 1, $out = array ..."Could not open input file: \phpdoc" ...

exec('dot -V', $out, $ret);
echo var_dump($out); // $ret = 1, $out = empty array
```

So, am I missing something?.

EDIT: exec() is working fine, it works for some of my environment variables like pear, cmd, among others, it does not work for the specified above

> phpdoc 
>   dot (GraphViz)

Even though they work on my command prompt and are well configured in my windows environment.

EDIT2: 
@Stefan Cvetkovic
I gues this is the part that you want to see from the result when running this command

> shell_exec("set"):
>
> Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\xampp\php; PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Is it possible that php has no access to my "dot" path, because this is missing from that result:

```
...C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\graphviz\bin
```

dot.exe is located in C:\xampp\php\pear\phpDocumentor\vendor\graphviz\bin and it is well configured as I can run `> dot -V` from my command prompt.
I have also tried changing its position in the PATH variable without luck.

Comment: Shouldn't the `exec()` be disabled by safe mode? Have you set the safe mode off?

Comment: exec() is fine, it works with some commands, but it is not working with some others.

Answer (score 2):

Although two years late, I found myself in the same situation and found a solution:

```
<?php
putenv('PATH=' . $_SERVER['PATH']);
$currentBranch = exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD');
```

The environment variable is missing for unknown reason in `exec` call,

but it does exists in `$_SERVER['PATH']`, the code just put it back and it works

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same issue.
In case anyone is having the same problem, make sure to restart the webserver (apache in my setup) because the PATH-variable was set recently and therefore was not available for the process (httpd) which was started prior to setting the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `gettype` on arrays or vars that are in question.

Barring that, I would also run the `phpinfo()` to see if that item is enabled in your server (or php.ini which I'm sure you checked?).

Saw a few interesting notes on exec [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and shell exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php, where an item needs admin privileges to run. Perhaps it applies?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shell_exec()`.

On linux platform for example i can't use exec to retrieve lm-sensors data, but with shell_exec i can, and you will get complete output as sting.

[shell_exec() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Edit:

Try this:

```
$command = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shellCommand = $command->Exec("C:\program.exe");
```

Now grab the output.

```
$standard = $shellCommand->StdOut->ReadAll;    # Standard output
$error = $shellCommand->StdErr->ReadAll;       # Error
```

Comment: I've tried shell_exec() as well, with the same results: echo shell_exec('phpdoc -V'); // Could not open input file: \phpdoc. Also, for echo shell_exec('dot -V'); // empty string

Comment: Can you try first to run shell_exec("set"); and post result.

Comment: I added a second edit (EDIT2), my path variable is OK, but it seems that php can't access to all of its elements.